# notro rpi firmware not working on rpi B+

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, pi-b+

I'm trying to setup [this](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/3-5-inch-B-B-LCD-Touch-Screen-Display-Module-320x480-for-Raspberry-Pi-V3-0-5Y-/281815847064?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6368) touchscreen 3.5inch RPi Display on an RPi B+ running Rasbain using [this](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/) tutorial which no longer works. I have been googling for the past 5 days trying to find a method that works. dose anyone know a driver that works, or a way to make notros one work?

Comment: Are you sure that Raspbian Light is supported? You may need the full Raspbian package which includes the x-windows packages.

Comment: What Steve says, plus a caveat that goes with buying products that have do not even have a web page: You are gambling.  If it works out you saved some money.  If it doesn't and you don't know what you are doing, there's a quick lesson about what *gambling* means.  Some of those screens work with a generic driver and some do not.  The people who make that end product do not make all the parts and they are gambling too, because this often mean they *cannot* support them and the gamble is a low price and low margin will still amount to profit. If they sell enough they win. It doesn't mean you do.

Comment: ill try the full version. the only reason I used the light one, is it wont take 6 hours to download.

Comment: I tried the full vision @SteveRobillard with the same effect.

Comment: there are some related conversations [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=136558) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=119088) you might want to checkout. if you can share the output of `dmesg`, there might be some clues worth investigating further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by doing:

```
wget http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/3/3d/LCD-show-160811.tar.gz
tar xvf LCD-show-YYMMDD.tar.gz
cd LCD-show/
./LCD35-show
```

from [here](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)#Method_1._Driver_installation)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have luck with your gamble ;) try to find out wich IC is used and may you found support for it by notro then you can try it with the fbtft.
[Notro ftbft support list](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/LCD-Modules)

Comment: the screen isn't the problem, the same thing happens with no screen plugged in.

Comment: also my screen is suported

Comment: seams to be your os version ... more specific the firmware have a look http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern and here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=47477

Comment: I replaced those files with clean ones and it booted, but the screen dose't work. it is those files that is the problem